# External arrows in tables

Tags: tables, tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

How to achieve similar arrows as in the picture?

[image]

The main issue cause of arrow

a(2,1) -> a(1,3), a(3,1) -> a(1,4), etc. Or at least how to make them on top of the table, but to make it look readable.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,row sep=3mm,column sep=3mm,nodes in empty cells]
{
  $a_{11}$ & $a_{12}$ & $a_{13}$ & $a_{14}$ & $a_{15}$ &  $\dots$ \\
  $a_{21}$ & $a_{22}$ & $a_{23}$ & $a_{24}$ & $a_{25}$ &          \\
  $a_{31}$ & $a_{32}$ & $a_{33}$ & $a_{34}$ & $a_{35}$ &          \\
  $a_{41}$ & $a_{42}$ & $a_{43}$ & $a_{44}$ & $a_{45}$ &          \\
  $a_{51}$ & $a_{52}$ & $a_{53}$ & $a_{54}$ & $a_{55}$ &          \\
  $\vdots$ &          &          &          &          & $\ddots$ \\
};

\begin{scope}[thick,black,->]
\draw (A-1-1)--(A-1-2);
\draw (A-1-2)--(A-2-2);
\draw (A-2-2)--(A-2-1);
%\draw (A-2-1)--(A-1-3);
\draw (A-1-3)--(A-2-3);
\draw (A-2-3)--(A-3-3);
\draw (A-3-3)--(A-3-2);
\draw (A-3-2)--(A-3-1);
%\draw (A-3-1)--(A-1-4);
% etc.
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do some simple calculations with the coordinates with the `calc` library. You can either choose the manual way (commented) or go with the macro `\turnArrow`. Needless to say, you may edit both of them.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\newcommand\turnArrow[2]{
\draw (A-#1-1) 
    -- +($0.25*(A-1-1)-0.25*(A-1-#2)$)
    -- ($1.5*(A-1-1)-0.25*(A-1-#2)-0.25*(A-#2-1)+(0,0.5em)$) 
    -- ($(A-1-#2)+0.25*(A-1-1)-0.25*(A-#2-1)+(0,0.5em)$) 
    --(A-1-#2)
    ;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,row sep=3mm,column sep=3mm,nodes in empty cells]
{
  $a_{11}$ & $a_{12}$ & $a_{13}$ & $a_{14}$ & $a_{15}$ &  $\dots$ \\
  $a_{21}$ & $a_{22}$ & $a_{23}$ & $a_{24}$ & $a_{25}$ &          \\
  $a_{31}$ & $a_{32}$ & $a_{33}$ & $a_{34}$ & $a_{35}$ &          \\
  $a_{41}$ & $a_{42}$ & $a_{43}$ & $a_{44}$ & $a_{45}$ &          \\
  $a_{51}$ & $a_{52}$ & $a_{53}$ & $a_{54}$ & $a_{55}$ &          \\
  $\vdots$ &          &          &          &          & $\ddots$ \\
};

\begin{scope}[thick,black,->]
\draw (A-1-1)--(A-1-2);
\draw (A-1-2)--(A-2-2);
\draw (A-2-2)--(A-2-1);
%\draw (A-2-1) 
%   -- +(-1.5em,0) 
%   -- ($(A-1-1)+(-1.5em,1.5em)$) 
%   -- ($(A-1-3)+(0,1.5em)$) 
%   -- (A-1-3);
    \turnArrow{2}{3}
\draw (A-1-3)--(A-2-3);
\draw (A-2-3)--(A-3-3);
\draw (A-3-3)--(A-3-2);
\draw (A-3-2)--(A-3-1);
%\draw (A-3-1)
%   -- +(-2em,0) 
%   -- ($(A-1-1)+(-2.0em,2.0em)$) 
%   -- ($(A-1-4)+(0,2.0em)$) 
%   -- (A-1-4);
    \turnArrow{3}{4}
    \turnArrow{4}{5}
    \turnArrow{5}{6}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to add some table horizontal rule, for instance, between the first and the second rows?

Comment: @Diaa. You can both draw anything you like and you can also used the package https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs as if you typeset a regular table. Would you please ask a separate question?

Comment: Sorry for the naive question. I didn't even try to look carefully at the code so I could see the obvious answer. Thanks for consideration.

Comment: @Diaa. Please, do not apologise for a naive but good question. I am guilty of having moments like that quite often.